# How to load a dll in an AppDomain with different NET version

Tags: appdomain, appdomainsetup

I have some third party assembly which was build using Net 2.0. Although I can of course reference that assembly in net 4, running the app results in all kinds of strange errors.

So I though loading it in a separate application domain will fix the problem but it does not. I assume it is still executed using the Net 4 runtime. Is there any way to force execution of an application domain in a different net version ?

I use CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap and than call the proxy.

Thanks for any help

Joe

Comment: Could you show your code? Could you show the exact error message you are getting? The exception stacktrace might be helpful as well.

Comment: The code is straight forward. I a dll compiled with net 2.0 i call a method of my referenced third party dll compiled in net 2.0:

Comment: `public class TestClass : System.MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void CallTestMethod(string pSomeData)
        {
            var lIntance = new ThirdPartyObject();
            lIntance.TestMethod();
        }
    }
`
In a console app compiled with net 4.0 I call the method in the app domain:

`AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain", null, null);

MyNameSapce.TestClass testInstance =(MyNameSapce.TestClass)newDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap
            (@"C:\TestClass.dll", "MyNameSapce.TestClass");
            testInstance.CallTestMethod("Test");`

Comment: The error is "clr has detected an invalid program". If I compile the calling app in net 2.0 it all works. So the third party dll seems to use some weird dynamic method creation or other MSIL stuff which is not compatible with the NET 4 jitter which I know changed significantly to NET 2.0.

So question is how can I force the call in the AppDomain to be executed in the net 2 environment using the Net 2.0 mscoree and mscrojit ?

It is basically what IIS does with the app pools where I can set different net versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [supportedRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) configuration element to set the CLR version of an AppDomain. If you do not want to add this to your app.config, you can add a second .config file that will be used during the construction of the new AppDomain. Have a look at [AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I still get the CLR Invalid Program Error. I suspect that setting the version to 2.0 in the config file maybe just results in using the NET2 core assemblies but still the 4 jitter ? Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create AppDomain. And Create DomainManager:MarshalByRef object in new domain.
2. DomainManager Load Assembly To created(new) domain.

> AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
>             AppDomain managerAD = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AD1", null, ads);
>
> ```
>       Assembly asm = managerAD.Load(typeof(DomainManager).Assembly.FullName);
>       string typeName = typeof(DomainManager).FullName;
>
>       DomainManager manager = (DomainManager)managerAD.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(asm.GetName().Name,
> ```
>
> typeName);
>       public class DomainManager : MarshalByRefObject
>         {
>
> ```
>     public void GetAppDomain(string assemblyFileName)
>     {
>       Assembly asm2 = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFileName);
>       Type neededType = asm2.GetType(<paste type>);
>       object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(procType);
>     }
> ```